# Forecasting one month data in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, regression, forecasting

I am trying to forecast % of DAU users based on the adoption rate of the iOS14 operating system. For example, I have 8 days date of both the adoption rate (in table 1) % DAU users for the first 8 days, but I would like to calculate 30 days (until end of May) forward.

Table 1: Adoption Rate

| Date | Adoption rate |
| --- | --- |
| April 26, 2021 | 0.70% |
| April 27, 2021 | 2.07% |
| April 28, 2021 | 3.71% |
| April 29, 2021 | 4.77% |
| April 30, 2021 | 6.16% |
| May 1, 2021 | 6.88% |
| May 2, 2021 | 7.15% |
| May 3, 2021 | 7.66% |

Table 2: % DAU

| Date | Adoption rate |
| --- | --- |
| April 26, 2021 | 100.00% |
| April 27, 2021 | 92.27% |
| April 28, 2021 | 93.21% |
| April 29, 2021 | 91.39% |
| April 30, 2021 | 90.32% |
| May 1, 2021 | 83.62% |
| May 2, 2021 | 81.60% |
| May 3, 2021 | 80.23% |

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the `TREND` function can help you, applied to just table 2?

`TREND(known_data_y, [known_data_x], [new_data_x], [b])`

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094263?hl=en-GB